# How can I solve this query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variable-declaration

[Sql Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f80976/1)

I have this table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200),
  `balance` decimal NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `client` (`id`, `name`, `balance`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Pepito', '500');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `balance_Movements` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clientId` int(6),
  `movementType` varchar(200),
  `import` decimal NOT NULL,
  `dateMovement` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `balance_Movements` (`id`, `clientid`, `movementType`, `import`, `dateMovement`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'payment', '50', '2018/05/11'),
  ('2', '1', 'refund', '25.05', '2018/05/10'),
  ('3', '1', 'refund', '60', '2018/04/06'),
  ('4', '1', 'payment', '100', '2018/04/03');
```

Client has at the start : 500€ --> so the declare variable will be like this:

```
declare @total_balance as decimal;
set @total_balance = (select balance from client where id = 1);

Result
------
500
```

I need to change after the result of @total_balance, taking the value for the last row:

Example:

```
Table_balance_Movements
------------------------

    Total
    -----
    450
    475.05
    535.05
    435.05
```

**Explanation:**

**450 -->** The client start with 500, so if the type of movement is payment I need to substract the balance of client to the import movement, and save the data in  @total_balance to use it later = 500 - 50 = 450

**475.05 -->** I get the value for @total_balance and sum 25.05 because in this line the type of movement is refund = 450 + 25.05 =   475.05

**535.05 -->** the same thing, I get the value from the @total_balance variable and see what type of movement is and substract or sum the import = 475.05 + 60 = 535.05

**435.05 -->** 535.05 - 100 =   435.05

I want to do something similar to this concept:

```
  declare @total_balance as decimal;
set @total_balance = (select balance from client where id = 1);

select (case when movementType = 'payment' then (@total_balance = @total_balance - import) 
             when movementType = 'refund' then (@total_balance = @total_balance + import)  end) as total 
from balance_Movements;
```

it would be possible? thanks

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  If you are using SQL Server, why is your sample code and SQL Fiddle using MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think he want a solution for SQL Server, cause he has it on MySQL.

Comment: @Sami he or she :) ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The OP, so _he_ :-)

Comment: because I could not load the code in sql, it was not loaded in the fiddle, but the code is in sql server

Comment: Is not he is she  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is using `SUM` with condition aggregate function window function to get accumulate the add with `balance`

```
SELECT c.balance +SUM(CASE WHEN movementType = 'payment' THEN - import
                           WHEN movementType = 'refund' THEN  import
                      ELSE 0 END
            ) OVER(ORDER BY b.id)   Total
FROM client c 
JOIN balance_Movements b on c.id = b.clientid
```

But if your dbms didn't support  window function, you can try to use correctly subquery in `select`

```
SELECT c.balance + 
(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN movementType = 'payment' THEN - import
                            WHEN movementType = 'refund' THEN  import
                          ELSE 0 END)
    FROM balance_Movements bb
    WHERE bb.id <= b.id and b.clientid = bb.clientid
)  Total
FROM client c 
JOIN balance_Movements b on c.id = b.clientid
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdb72416182187b45c2bf87baa6c9801)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with the cumulative sum window functions.  The following will work in SQL Server and MySQL 8+

```
select c.*,
       (c.balance +
        sum(case when bm.movement_type = 'payment' then - import
                 when bm.movement_type = 'refund' then import
            end) over (partition by c.id order by bm.datemovement)
       ) as net_balance
from client c join
     balance_movements bm
     on bm.clientid = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the sum of refunds and subtract the sum of payments like this:

```
SELECT 500 +
(SELECT SUM(import) FROM balance_Movements WHERE movementType = 'refund')
- (SELECT SUM(import) FROM balance_Movements WHERE movementType = 'payment') AS total
```

Result: 435.05

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#balance_Movements', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #balance_Movements; END;

CREATE TABLE #balance_Movements (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    clientId INT,
    movementType VARCHAR (200),
    import DECIMAL (9, 2) NOT NULL,
    dateMovement DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO #balance_Movements (id, clientid, movementType, import, dateMovement) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'payment', '50', '2018/05/11'),
  ('2', '1', 'refund', '25.05', '2018/05/10'),
  ('3', '1', 'refund', '60', '2018/04/06'),
  ('4', '1', 'payment', '100', '2018/04/03');

--=============================================================

DECLARE @_start DECIMAL(9,2) = 500;

SELECT 
    *,
    running_total = @_start - SUM(CASE WHEN bm.movementType = 'refund' THEN -1 * bm.import ELSE bm.import END) OVER (PARTITION BY bm.clientId ORDER BY bm.dateMovement desc)
FROM
    #balance_Movements bm;
```

Results...

```
id          clientId    movementType import     dateMovement            running_total
----------- ----------- ------------ ---------- ----------------------- --------------
1           1           payment      50.00      2018-05-11 00:00:00.000 450.00
2           1           refund       25.05      2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 475.05
3           1           refund       60.00      2018-04-06 00:00:00.000 535.05
4           1           payment      100.00     2018-04-03 00:00:00.000 435.05
```